# Android application automatically not creating a directory to save the image captured by my application

Tags: java, android

I developing a OCR text to speech app for android. i was struck on middle. when i run the app it detecting the document and beep the camera shutter sound and showing "Unexpectedly application has stopped"
please someone help me to solve this problem.
image capturing, saving to storage and saving the text file are coded on both of bellow classes

HelloOpenCvActivity.java

```
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;
 import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
 import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
 import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
 import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
 import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
 import org.opencv.core.Mat;
 import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
 import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
 import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
 import android.media.Ringtone;
 import android.media.RingtoneManager;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloOpenCvActivity extends Activity implements
CvCameraViewListener2, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

public static TextToSpeech mTts;
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;
private HelloViewer mOpenCvCameraView;
private boolean killed = false;
private Uri notification;
private Ringtone ringTone;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private MenuItem mItemLanguage = null;
private boolean mIsJavaCamera = true;
public static String lang = "eng";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.opencv_layout);

    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (HelloViewer) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    notification = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
            notification);


    // Fire off an intent to check if a TTS engine is installed
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //shutdownCamera();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    shutdownCamera();

    if (mTts != null) {
        mTts.stop();
        mTts.shutdown();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(Util.TAG, "Sleeping failed before starting camera view. ", e);
    }
    Size resolution = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolution();
    mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(resolution);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setAutoFocus();
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat mRgba = null;
    try {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

            contours.add(DetectSquares.find(mRgba));
            if (contours.get(0) != null) {
                Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

                if (!killed) {
                    killed = true;
                    ringTone.play();

                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ringTone.stop();
                            captureImage();
                        }
                    }, 4 * 1000);
                }
            } else {
                killed = false;
                ringTone.stop();
                timer.cancel();
            }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e(Util.TAG, "Error occured" + exc.getMessage());
    }

    return mRgba;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     mItemLanguage = menu.add("Toggle between languages");
     return true;
}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String toastMesage = new String();
        Log.i(Util.TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

        if (item == mItemLanguage) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.GONE);
            mIsJavaCamera = !mIsJavaCamera;

            if (mIsJavaCamera) {
                String english = "Language English is selected";
                toastMesage = english;
                lang = "eng";
                mTts.speak(english, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            } else {
                String sinhala = "Language Sinhala is selected";
                toastMesage = sinhala;
                lang = "sin";
                mTts.speak(sinhala, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }

            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastMesage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        return true;
    }


 @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void captureImage() {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/project/" + currentDateandTime;

            mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e(Util.TAG, "Error in capture image", exc);
        }
    }


private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: 
            Log.i(Util.TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            break;
        default: 
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this,
            mLoaderCallback);
}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing TTS data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInit(int arg0) {
    // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
    mTts.speak("Place your mobile on top of the document, and move it up slowly.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

private void shutdownCamera() {
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
        if (mOpenCvCameraView.getCamera() != null) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.getCamera().stopPreview();
            mOpenCvCameraView.getCamera().release();
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCamera(null);
        }
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}}}
```

HelloViewer.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloViewer extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback, ShutterCallback {

private String mPictureFileName;
public HelloViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
    disconnectCamera();

    mMaxHeight = 480; // resolution.width;
    mMaxWidth = 640; // resolution.height;

    //connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    // Sets the preview size of camera.

    connectCamera(getWidth(),getHeight());
}

public Size getResolution() {
    List<Camera.Size> sizes  = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        Log.i(Util.TAG, "Picture sizes height : " + size.height + ", width : " + size.width);
    }

    return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

public void setAutoFocus() {
    Log.i(Util.TAG, "Seting autofocus mode to Continuous picture.");
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
    // Enable in nexus 3
    //parameters.setPictureSize(2592, 1944);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}

public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
    Log.i(Util.TAG, "Taking picture");

    this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
    // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
    mCamera.takePicture(this, null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.i(Util.TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
    HelloOpenCvActivity.mTts.speak("Please wait, Character recognition process is in progress.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpg format)
    try {
        File file = new File(mPictureFileName + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Util.TAG, "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    } finally {
        processOCR(mPictureFileName);
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        // TODO: Stop this recall and let the program terminate.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    }
}




public void processOCR(String mPictureFileName2) {
    try {
        Log.i(Util.TAG, "Started processing OCR");

        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask();
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> aTask = task.execute(mPictureFileName + ".jpg");

        OCRProcessor ocr = new OCRProcessor();
        String text = ocr.getOCRText(aTask.get());

        // Write text to file
        HelloOpenCvActivity.mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        Log.i(Util.TAG, "TEXT \n" + text);
        writeToFile(text, mPictureFileName + ".txt");
    } 
    catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e(Util.TAG, "Error occured in processing OCR", exc);
        HelloOpenCvActivity.mTts.speak("Error occurred in processing document, Please refetch the document", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}

private void writeToFile(String text, String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(text);
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Util.TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}

@Override
public void onShutter() {
}

public Camera getCamera() {
    return mCamera;
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    this.mCamera = camera;
}}
```

This is part of Logcat file for the app when run

```
 11-02 12:58:16.862: I/dalvikvm-heap(19979): Grow heap (frag case) 
 to  14.125MB for 4519746-byte allocation
 11-02 12:58:16.882: I/DREAMVISION::(19979): Saving a bitmap to file

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979): Exception in photoCallback

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):       
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/project
 /2015-11-02_12-58-16.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
 directory)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:449)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:77)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.HelloViewer.onPictureTaken(HelloViewer.java:81)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:932)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
 (ZygoteInit.java:849)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979): Caused by: 
 libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
 directory)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:440)

 11-02 12:58:16.892: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    ... 11 more

 11-02 12:58:16.892: I/DREAMVISION::(19979): Started processing OCR

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/BitmapFactory(19979): Unable to decode stream: 
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/project  
 /2015-11-02_12-58-16.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
 directory)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979): Error occured in  
 processing  OCR

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979): 
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:483)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.HelloViewer.processOCR(HelloViewer.java:107)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.HelloViewer.onPictureTaken(HelloViewer.java:88)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:932)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndAr
 gsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at   
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979): Caused by: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.BitmapWorkerTask.rotateBitMap(BitmapWorkerTask.java:26)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapWorkerTask.java:17)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 com.hello.BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapWorkerTask.java:1)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at  
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolEx 
 ecutor.java:1112)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExe 
 cutor. java:587)

 11-02 12:58:16.902: E/DREAMVISION::(19979):    at 
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `HelloViewer.java`:

```
...
File file = new File(mPictureFileName + ".jpg");
File folder = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
folder.mkdirs();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
...
```

Comment: getCanonicalFile() is not defined in my class. is there have any other methods?

Comment: It is a File class method, not your class. You can check it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29)

Comment: I wrote the getParent method instead of getParentFile. This was wrong and that's why it failed to find the getCanonicalFile method in the String class.